# Python group by and Combine all Text

Tags: python, pandas, join, nlp

Working on an NLP Project in python is there a way to group all feedback below per specific Issue Group?

```py
Out[40]:
           Issue Group           Feedback   
        24 Accessories           Nope, just make a longer charging cord :)
        49 Accessories           Everything was very helpful and nice handled
      1003 Connectivity          kEEP DOING WHAT YOU ARE DOING.
      2003 Connectivity          None! Keep up the good work!

Desired Result will be: 

           Issue Group            Feedback
           Accessories            Nope, just make a longer charging cord :) Everything was very helpful and nice handled
           Connectivity           kEEP DOING WHAT YOU ARE DOING None! Keep up the good work!
```

Comment: th output is a list??

Comment: yeah a list of text

Comment: in the declaration of text = [  ] ....  " is there a way to get all feedback go through connectivity vs Accessories? I have 4,200 rows spread across these 2. I hope there is another way to do it.. thank you so much

Comment: your input is an list or a dataframe?

Comment: input wise it's a dataframe feed from a csv.file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try groupby,

```
df.groupby('Issue Group').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Output of this will be text separated by comma ,

```
Nope, just make a longer charging cord :),Everything was very helpful and nice handled
kEEP DOING WHAT YOU ARE DOING,None! Keep up the good work!
```

If you want list in the output,

```
df.groupby('Issue Group').agg(list)
```

Output of this will be in the form list as follows,

```
['Nope, just make a longer charging cord :)', 'Everything was very helpful and nice handled']
['kEEP DOING WHAT YOU ARE DOING', 'None! Keep up the good work!']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example :

```
import pandas as pd

text = [ ('Accessories','Nope, just make a longer charging cord :)') ,
             ('Accessories','Everything was very helpful and nice handled' ) ,
             ('Connectivity','kEEP DOING WHAT YOU ARE DOING'),
            ('Connectivity','None! Keep up the good work!') ]

df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['Col1' , 'Col2']) 
print(pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Col1'],values='Col2',aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(x)))
```